# Grant Active-Directory-Synced group permission to a SharePoint Folder in a library using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, directory

We have a SharePoint Online Site, which contain many Sub sites, Each sub site has one Document library containing 15 folders. We want to set for each folder different permission to different Active-Directory-Synced security groups.
For example

```
         Group1  Group2  Group3

Folder1    RO     RO       RW
Folder2    NA     RW       RO
..
Folder15   RW     RW       RO
```

(RO:Read Only , RW: Read-Write, NA:No Access)

For this purpose, we need first to break the inheritance from the folders from their parents, I managed to achieve this using this PS code, where SPOMod.psm1 is available online for free Here https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Module-for-5ecbbcf0

---

```
$cred=Get-Credential
Import-Module "D:\somepath\SharePoint Onlince Client Components SDK\SPOMod.psm1" -verbose

Connect-SPOCSOM -Credential $cred -Url "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects_Division/ProjectnameAndLocation"
Get-SPOListItems -ListTitle Documents  -Recursive  -IncludeAllProperties $true | select ID
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 1
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 2
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 3
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 4
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 5
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 6
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 7
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 8
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 9
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 10
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 11
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 12
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 13
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 14
Remove-SPOListItemInheritance -ListTitle Documents -KeepPermissions $false  -ItemID 15
```

Where ItemID 1 to 15 are the folders ID that were first created on this library.
This works fine with me.

### The next step is to assign the AD Group permissions on each folder. For this purpose I'm trying to use this PS code which I got from here (http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/09/sharepoint-online-set-folder-permissions-powershell.html)

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Variables
$SiteURL="https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/Projects_Division/Project1nameAndLocation"
$FolderURL="Documents/Folder1" #Relative URL of the 1st Folder
$GroupName="ActiveDirectory Group1 Name" #The AD Group that we want to assign for Folder1
$UserAccount="useraccount@company.com" An AD Account that we want to also assign
$PermissionLevel="Read"


$Cred= Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
$Web = $Ctx.web

#Get the Folder
$Folder = $Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderURL)
$Ctx.Load($Folder)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Break Permission inheritence - Remove all existing list permissions & keep Item level permissions
$Folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($False,$True)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Write-host -f Yellow "Folder's Permission inheritance broken..."

#Get the SharePoint Group & User
$Group =$Web.SiteGroups.GetByName($GroupName)
$User = $Web.EnsureUser($UserAccount)
$Ctx.load($Group)
$Ctx.load($User)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery() #The error is happening here and the script stopps

#Grant permission
#Get the role required
$Role = $web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName($PermissionLevel)
$RoleDB = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($Ctx)
$RoleDB.Add($Role)

#Assign permissions
$GroupPermissions =     $Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($Group,$RoleDB)
$UserPermissions = $Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($User,$RoleDB)
$Folder.Update()
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Write-host "Permission Granted Successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green 
-----
```

I’m getting an error at #Get the SharePoint Group & User while executing the query:

```
------
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\code> $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Group cannot be found."
At line:1 char:5
+     $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
----
```

Despite the group is successfully AD Synced, and it appears in SharePoint GUI if I try to do the same from GUI.

What I noticed and tested that this code works perfectly if the group was local SharePoint Online Group (not AD Synched)  Is there a command to allow me to use AD-Synched group the same way?

Answer (score 0):

$Group =$Web.SiteGroups.GetByName($GroupName) gets the SharePoint Groups only.

Use:
$ADGroup = $Web.EnsureUser("Domain\ADGroup") to resolve AD Groups!